# httr::content returning object type externalptr

Tags: r, docker, api, httr, google-cloud-run

I have a function that calls an API using `httr::get` and `httr::content`. Locally, this works as expected; a list is returned that I then parse as needed. When I put this in a Dockerfile and run it on Google Cloud Run, though, it seem as though the response from the `httr::content` function results in an object of type 'externalptr' rather than a list. this then makes the rest of my function unworkable, and yields the following error message:

```
<simpleError in response[[k]]$id: object of type 'externalptr' is not subsettable>
```

So I'm assuming a change to my Dockerfile may be what is needed, given that all works well locally? My Dockerfile is like so:

```
FROM rocker/r-ver:3.6.0
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y make \
  libcurl4-openssl-dev libssl-dev libxml2-dev zlib1g-dev curl
RUN ["install2.r", "assertthat", "glue", "httr", "lubridate", "dplyr","tibble","plumber","xml2","remotes"]
RUN R -e "remotes::install_github('simitpatel/wordpressr')"
COPY ["./", "./"]
ENTRYPOINT ["R", "-e", "pr <- plumber::plumb(rev(commandArgs())[1]); pr$run(host='0.0.0.0', port=as.numeric(Sys.getenv('PORT')))"]
CMD ["api.R"]
```

But I'm at a loss for next steps. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The Docker File is less intertersting than what R code you are actually running. Where is the call to `content()`? What type of content are you expecting? Are you explicitly passing a `type=` to `content()`?

Comment: @MrFlick i am expecting a list in response. the call is like so:

 ```response <- content(GET(paste0(root_url,'/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=100&page=',j)))```

so i'm not specifying a value for the `type` argument. should i try ``` ```response <- content(GET(paste0(root_url,'/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=100&page=',j)),type = 'application/json')``` ?

Comment: Getting an externalptr object makes me think you are getting a html respond rather than a JSON one which might indicate a bad request. Are you checking the http status code for the request?